# Adding users from CSV in Linux using BASH

Tags: bash, parsing, csv, user-accounts

My CSV file contains the information needed like this firstname,lastname,userid. I have 5 users which i need to parse from the CSV. In order to create the account assign to a group(group1) and assign encrypted temporary passwords. I've hit a wall, any help would be awesome. Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","

while read firstname lastname userid 
 do 
    useradd -c "$firstname $lastname -d /home/$userid -G group1 -s /bin/bash $userid"
done
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

No users are being added from script execution.

Comment: Whats wrong with what you have got ?

Comment: @1up You have an un-closed quote. But there's no way of knowing whether that's the cause since you haven't properly described the problem.

Comment: Getting an Error on line 8 when I execute in BASH; ./Parse.sh: line 8: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./Parse.sh: line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @1up As I said: Un-closed quote. Using an editor with syntax highlight helps. And/or http://www.shellcheck.net

Comment: Got the unclosed quote, now I just don't see the users being added.

Comment: @1up It looks like you send all your data as a comment to `useradd`. I *think* you meant to put quotes around each parameter.

Comment: Like this you mean? useradd -c "$firstname $lastname" -d "/home/$userid" -G "student" -s "/bin/bash $userid"

Comment: @1up Yeah, something like that. Just try it.

Comment: I did, same result, wondering if I'm missing a perameter, and if that's the main fail.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you.

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","

while read firstname lastname userid 
do 
     useradd -c "${firstname} ${lastname}" -d /home/"${userid}" -G group1 -s /bin/bash "${userid}"
done < file.csv
```

Your script was fine, i have made few changes as below

1. Have quoted the variables, this will prevent unwanted expansions.
2. Resetting `IFS` is not necessary as the script runs in a subshell.
3. `while` needs a file input, so added it.

Comment: Thanks, I had also saved my file to the wrong location, hence the no change.

Comment: Regarding #4: The double quotes are enough. This way the single quotes will be sent to `useradd` (which may not be a problem).